# SQL LIKE operator for Graphic Strings

Tags: java, jpa, db2, jpql, openjpa

How can I use LIKE operator for the Graphic strings in OpenJPA for DB2?

I used as the following in the JPQL and failed.

```
select u from User u where u.userName like :userName
```

userName = VARGRAPHIC(20)

Then I use as the following and failed

```
   select u from User u where u.userName like CAST(:userName AS VARGRAPHIC(20))
```

Then I use as the following and failed

```
select u from User u where LOCATE(:userName,u.userName) > 0
```

I tried switching from deferPrepare to true to false but still failed

### edited

with LOCATE

```
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=LOCATE;FUNCTION, DRIVER=3.63.75
```

with LIKE

```
  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=LIKE;FUNCTION, DRIVER=3.63.75
```

Any kind help is appreciated.

### edited

I concat the parameter with %%. The problem is seemed to be LIKE doesn't accept in-balanced operands.  Both must be a graphic string. So I set So I set

> RequiresCastForComparisons=true

, then the query result containing an escape(Which is using LIKE ESCAPE '\'). So I set

> `RequiresSearchStringEscapeForLike=false`

.

After those setting.
When I was searching the string 花火大会 
the with wild card paramter eg. %花% return empty records.

I will update the question with generated SQL tomorrow.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Failed how? Did your computer crash?

Comment: @mustaccio Sorry for not replying instantly. I updated my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, `LIKE` without any wildcards is equivalent to `=` (and presumably `LOCATE(...)` would ignore wildcards).  The error is complaining that it can't find `LIKE`/`LOCATE` as functions, which is really strange, to say the least.  What do the statements actually run look like (not the JPQL - what actually gets run)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the wildcard character as doublebyte "％"　instead of normal "%"
Hope that this will help someone.